# Problema login Cookies Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, cookies

amigos necesitaba un código que me autologueara después de registrarme, y lo he logrado con el siguiente:

```
$id = wp_insert_user($data);
//so if the return is not an wp error object then continue with login
if(!is_wp_error($id)){
    wp_set_current_user($id); // set the current wp user
    wp_set_auth_cookie($id); // start the cookie for the current registered user
}
```

y este otro también funciona, lo escribo en mi código justo después de registrarlos con wp_insert.

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'auto_login_user' );
function auto_login_user($user_id) {
    wp_set_current_user($user_id); // set the current wp user
    wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id); // start the cookie for the current registered user
}
//this code is a bit tricky, if you are admin and you want to create a user then your admin session will be replaced with the new user you created :)
```

Sin embargo en modo localhost me funciona, pero al subirlo al servidor web, no loguea automáticamente, he notado que es por las cookies, si en el navegador las autorizo para el sitio, funciona, pero como hacer para que  esas cookies se autoricen en todos los usuarios posibles.

he instalado plugins de cookies pero no funciona.
alguna ayuda, de antemano gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

les comparto, he logrado solucionarlo solo enviando a una dirección del sitio

```
if(!is_wp_error($user_id)){
          wp_set_current_user($user_id); // set the current wp user
          wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id); // start the cookie for the current registered user
          header("location:members.php");
          return;
      }
```

Muchas gracias a todos, espero le sirva a alguien más que inicie en esto.